# Prove that a Collection of subsets of $E$ is a $\sigma$-algebra

Tags: integration, general-topology, measure-theory

Prove that:$\;$ $\mathscr C$ is a $\sigma$-algebra,with$\;$$E$ $\;$ is a infinite set.
$$\mathscr C\equiv\{A\subset\mathbb E\,|\,A\text{ is countable or }A^c\text{ is countable}\}.$$

Comment: What did you try ?

Comment: I don't have any Idea to Try am stuck in proving that every $A$ $\in \mathscr C$ implies that its compliment is in $\mathscr C$ and the stability of Infinite Unions

Comment: If $A\in\mathscr{C}$ you have to prove that $A^c\in\mathscr{C}$ that is $A^c$ or $(A^c)^c$ is countable... As for the reunion, do you know that a countable union of countable sets is also countable ?

Comment: To solve: What does $A \in \mathscr C$ mean?  Either $A$ is countable or $A^c$ is countable.  In each of those two cases, try to determine whether $A^c \in \mathscr C$.

Comment: You'll find that simple "Here's the statement of my question, solve it for me" posts will be poorly received. What is better is for you to add context (with an [edit]): What you understand about the problem, what you've tried so far, *etc.*; something both to show you are part of the learning experience and to help us guide you to the appropriate help. You can consult [this link](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/9959) for further guidance.

Comment: I get it Thank you. so i should take two cases when A is countable(case1) and $A^c$ is countable(case2)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We check the three conditions in the [definition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/%CE%A3-algebra#Definition) one by one.

First, $\mathbb{E} \in \mathscr{C}$ because $\mathbb{E}^c = \emptyset$ is countable.

Second, we verify that $\mathscr{C}$ is closed under complementation. Fix $A \in \mathscr{C}$. Either $A$ is countable or $A^c$ is countable. We need to prove that $A^c \in \mathscr{C}$. If $A$ is countable, then $A^c \in \mathscr{C}$ by virtue of $A^c$ having a countable complement. If $A^c$ is countable, then $A^c \in \mathscr{C}$ by virtue of $A^c$ being countable.

Finally, we verify that $\mathscr{C}$ is closed under countable unions. Fix $A_i \in \mathscr{C}$ for $i = 0, 1, 2, \dots$ and let $B = \cup_{i=0}^\infty A_i$. We need to prove that $B \in \mathscr{C}$. Either all $A_i$ are countable or there is $A_k$ whose complement is countable. In the former case, $B$ is countable as a countable union of countable sets. In the latter case, $B$ has countable complement, because $B^c \subset A_k^c$.

Comment: Thank you so much that was Useful for me.